# Creating multiple UnetSockets in UnetStack to exhaust the server

Tags: tcp, ddos, unetstack, syn

I am trying to implement an attack similar to a normal SYN flood attack in my network created on UnetStack. As UnetSocket() requires parameters like api and localhost to create a socket, providing fake or random api number results in error. So we have to create a node with that api  just to create the socket. Creating so many nodes simply to exhaust the server is not feasible from the attacker's point of view. Is there any way I can create the sockets more feasibly? I appreciate guidance from the expert in this domain. (If anything mentioned above is wrong, please correct me.)

Thank you

Comment: UnetStack does not use IP as the protocol, and so terms like SYN floor or even a raw socket don't mean anything in UnetStack. You need to be clearer about what exactly you are trying to achieve, rather than translate a tool use in IP networks to underwater networks.

Comment: I guess you got the wrong idea about my post. I know UnestStack does not use IP as the protocol. I just gave an example of how we do it normally. Secondly,I am not trying to use any tool here. My aim here is to find out any possible way to exhaust my server node through multiple connections. I tired it by creating multiple UnetSocket which requires api, I guess I am not wrong here. I can not use any random api here to simply create UnetSocket without having that node in my network. That's why I asked about any other possible way to do it.

Comment: Still, I have edited my question for more clarity to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: Thanks for trying to clarify, but unfortunately, I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to attack the IP network that is used for your application to connect to UnetStack via UnetSocket? Or are you trying to attack the underwater network? And why?

Comment: UnetSockets are used to connect to a Unet node using a Unix socket-like interface. For more information, you can refer to the Unet handbook here: https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_unetsocket_api.html